# Использование USB камеры

Tags: java, android, usb, камера

Как в Android получать фото/видео с USB веб-камеры? Необходима поддержка API-19.

Comment: Попробуйте этот вариант http://brain.cc.kogakuin.ac.jp/research/usb-e.html

Comment: Или эту библиотеку https://github.com/openxc/android-webcam